# Fragments not responding to buttonclicks

Tags: c#, android, xml, xaml, android-fragments

I have a problem with my app. Firstly, I made two Tabs using **fragments** which inflates an **activity**. The tabs implemented is working fine. Secondly i have  displayed the **XAML** right. However there is not possible to interact with the buttons, but it's possible to write in the text fields. The text fields will however not respond when i try to update them with the buttons.

The activities work properly not using the fragments, any clue what I can do? Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Here is my code:

---

**MainActivity Code:**

```
public class TabActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            //Toolbar
            SupportToolbar toolbar = FindViewById<SupportToolbar>(Resource.Id.toolBar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            //ActionBar
            SupportActionBar actionBar = SupportActionBar;
            actionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu);
            actionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            //Drawer 
            mDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);
            NavigationView navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            if(navigationView != null)
            {
                setUpDrawerContent(navigationView);
            }
            //Tabs 
            TabLayout tabs = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.tabs);

            ViewPager viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewpager);
            setUpViewPager(viewPager);

            tabs.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);
            };
    }


    // What Actually sets my tabs
        private void setUpViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
        {
        //====================================
            //SET THE FRAGMENTS HERE.
        //====================================
            TabAdapter adapter = new TabAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);
            adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment1(), "Inventar");
            adapter.AddFragment(new Fragment2(), "Onskeliste");

            viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
        }
        public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.ItemId)
            {
                //Checks if the drawer is opened all the way up
                case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
                    mDrawerLayout.OpenDrawer((int)GravityFlags.Left);
                    return true;
                default:
                    return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }
        private void setUpDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView)
        {
            navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += (object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e) =>
            {
                e.MenuItem.SetChecked(true);
                mDrawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            };
        }

        //===================================
        // Creating a tab adapter which inherrit from a fragment adaper, is used to adapt the viewpager and tabs together
        //===================================
        public class TabAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
        {

            public List<SupportFragment> Fragments { get; set; }
            public List<string> FragmentNames { get; set; }

            public TabAdapter (SupportoFragmentManager sfm) : base (sfm)
            {
                Fragments = new List<SupportFragment>();
                FragmentNames = new List<string>();
            }

            public void AddFragment(SupportFragment fragment, string name)
            {
                Fragments.Add(fragment);
                FragmentNames.Add(name);
            }

            public override int Count
            {
                get
                {
                    return Fragments.Count;
                }
            }

            //Gets the item of the fragemnt at the specific possition
            public override SupportFragment GetItem(int position)
            {
                return Fragments[position];
            }

            //Sets the title of the fragment 
            public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
            {
                return new Java.Lang.String(FragmentNames[position]);
            }
        }
    }`
```

---

**Fragment 1**

```
public class Fragment1 : SupportFragment
    {
        public override void OnInflate(Activity activity, IAttributeSet attrs, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnInflate(activity, attrs, savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            //Inflates the view under the tabs 
            View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Inventory, container, false);

            return view;
        }
    }
```

---

**XML File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/scroll2"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FBC855">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_my_cellar_page"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/signup_color"
                android:id="@+id/signup_number"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/number"
                    android:hint="Enter the amount of beer"
                    android:inputType="textCapWords"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/signup_number"
                android:id="@+id/registration"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Btn_lagre"
                    android:text="Lagre"
                    android:background="#6C2334"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="35dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/list_data"
                android:layout_below="@+id/registration"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_below="@+id/list_data"
                android:id="@+id/circularProgress"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:theme="@style/CircularProgress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_below="@+id/circularProgress"
                android:id="@+id/mycellar_inventory3"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <View
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#6C2334"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/Btn_inventartilbake"
                    android:text="Tilbake"
                    android:background="#6C2334"
                    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:background="#6C2334"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: The XML file is for your activity?

Comment: Yes, the xml file is for my activity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I assume that your XML file is for your activity.

Well you need to declare your buttens, if you want to interact with them. If the butten is in your activity, your need to declare it in your activity... otherwise, if your butten is in your fragment you need to declare it in your fragment.. in the Code below,i got a fragment where i have a butten declared in the fragments XML - inflate the fragement and afterwards i use the butten from the inflated fragment:

```
public class FragmentSettings : SupportFragment
{
    private Button mBtnOk;

    public FragmentSettings(Context context)
    {
        mContext = context;
    }

    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        //Inflate the fragment XML
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.FragmentSettings, container, false);

        //Grab the butten from the inflated fragment
        mBtnOk = view.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.mBtnOk);
        mBtnOk.Click += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        {
            //DO stuff
        };

        return view;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps - ask if there is somthing you dont understand?

Comment: Where do public FragmentSettings come from? and what does it ?

Comment: That is just a fragment i pulled from one of my own projects? Do you mean the XML i inflated?

Comment: Ok, i Figured it out now Thanks for the help! ^_^

Comment: I now bumped into another problem, how can I add a async method to the OnCreateView?

Comment: Maybe mark this question anwsered, edit your post and tell what you did to fix your problem so others can learn from it - and make a new question for the async method!

Comment: yeah, I should do that